# "bpy.path.abspath" not working properly

Tags: python, image, path

So I currently have this string: "//..\Desktop\vine.png"
However, to use it when loading an image I need the \ to be \\ , so:    "//..\\Desktop\\vine.png"

```
path = "//..\Desktop\vine.png"
image = bpy.data.images.load(path)
```

I've tried using

```
bpy.path.abspath(path)
```

however this is what it throws back at me:

[image]

For some reason it changes the "v" to "x0b" and doesn't change the last \ to a \\

Anyone have any ideas why this might be? Or any other methods to change the \ to \\

Comment: I did some more tests, it seems like it doesn't work if the image starts with following letters: v, n, b, x, f, a, u

Comment: use `path = "//..\Desktop\\vine.png"` or `path = r"//..\Desktop\vine.png"`

Comment: the path is generated, do you know if there is a way to use the r if path is a variable? like: bpy.path.abspath(r + path) ?

Comment: s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\")   -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262828/python-how-to-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal